# Retrieve an array from Postgres using Chapel CDO

Tags: postgresql, chapel

I am getting an error pulling an array from Postgres using the [Chapel CDO Library](https://github.com/marcoscleison/cdo)  I have a pg instance with the following table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aagg;
CREATE TABLE aagg (team text, name text);
INSERT INTO aagg VALUES ('Wonder Pets', 'Linny'); 
INSERT INTO aagg VALUES ('Wonder Pets', 'Ming Ming');
INSERT INTO aagg VALUES ('Wonder Pets', 'Tuck');
INSERT INTO aagg VALUES ('OJ Defense Team', 'F. Lee Bailey'); 
INSERT INTO aagg VALUES ('OJ Defense Team', 'Robert Shapiro');
INSERT INTO aagg VALUES ('OJ Defense Team', 'Johnny Cohchran');
```

I'm trying to pull it with the following chapel program

```
use Postgres;

config const DB_HOST: string = "localhost";
config const DB_USER: string = "buddha";
config const DB_NAME: string = "buddha";
config const DB_PWD: string = "buddha";


var con = PgConnectionFactory(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, database=DB_NAME, passwd=DB_PWD);
var cursor = con.cursor();
// Retrieve the data
const q = "SELECT team, array_agg(name) AS members FROM aagg GROUP BY team;"; 
cursor.query(q);

for row in cursor {
  writeln("Team: ", row['name'], "\tMembers: ", row['members'] );
  for member in row['members'] {
    writeln ("Special mention to ", member);
  }
}
```

But the loop breaks up the characters as in

```
Special mention to {
Special mention to "
Special mention to F
Special mention to .
Special mention to  
Special mention to L
Special mention to e
Special mention to e
Special mention to  
Special mention to B
Special mention to a
Special mention to i
Special mention to l
Special mention to e
Special mention to y
Special mention to "
```

How do I get this to recognize the array?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `row["column_name"]` or `row.get("column_name")`, you obtain the column value as string. However, Postgres can response query with a column array. To treat this, you should use the method **`row.getArray("column_name")`** to get a Postgres array as Chapel string array.

Ex.:

```
use Postgres;

config const DB_HOST: string = "localhost";
config const DB_USER: string = "buddha";
config const DB_NAME: string = "buddha";
config const DB_PWD:  string = "buddha";

var con = PgConnectionFactory( host=DB_HOST,
                               user=DB_USER,
                               database=DB_NAME,
                               passwd=DB_PWD
                               );
var cursor = con.cursor();

// Retrieve the data

const q = "SELECT team, array_agg(name) AS members FROM aagg GROUP BY team;"; 

cursor.query(q);

for row in cursor {

  writeln("Team: ", row['name'], "\tMembers: ", row['members'] );

  for member in row.getArray("members") {

    writeln ("Special mention to ", member);

  }

}
```